# Printing GMT and PST timestamp shows a difference of only 7 hours

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

My understanding is that PST differs from GMT / UTC by 8 hours.  However, when I print this out, I find only a difference of 7 hours.  Can you explain what I have done incorrectly here?

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    Date date = sdf1.parse("2014-05-01 13:31:03.7");

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssS");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Prints:

```
20140501_1331037
20140501_2031037
20140501_2031037
```

Comment: Avoid using the 3 or 4 letter codes for time zones. Those codes are neither standardized nor unique. Use [proper time zone names](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). These names are mostly combinations of continent, a slash, and a city or region. For US west coast, `America/Los_Angeles`. For Canada east, `America/Montreal`.

Comment: Handling time zones is much easier if you use Joda-Time or java.time rather than java.util.Date/.Calendar.

Comment: For the record, I am converting my code to use Joda Time as suggested above.

Comment: You won't regret the investment in learning Joda-Time. I added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27678571/642706) to get you started in the case of the this Question's problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are doing PST in summer/daylights saving time when it is GMT+7.  Try the middle of winter.

From http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.co.uk/time-zone/usa/pacific-time/

> When does Pacific Time change to Daylight Saving Time?
>
> In most states
>   in the USA and in most provinces in Canada, Daylight-Saving Time (DST)
>   is observed.  During DST PT or PDT is 7 hours behind Greenwich Mean
>   Time (GMT-7).
>
> After the Summer months Pacific Time is shifted back by 1 hour to US
>   Pacific Standard Time (PST) or (GMT-8).
>
> The schedule for the states of the United States that adopt daylight
>   saving time are:
>
> 2 a.m. on the Second Sunday in March to
>
> 2 a.m. on the First Sunday of
>   November.

Answer (score 6):

You have not done anything incorrectly here. If you add the timezone in to the output format:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH mm ssS Z z");
```

you can see the output is actually PDT (daylight savings) and not PST (regular)

```
10 31 037 -0700 PDT
17 31 037 +0000 GMT
17 31 037 +0000 UTC
12 31 037 -0500 EST
17 31 037 +0000 GMT
```

May is in Daylight saving time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution using Joda-Time 2.6.

```
String inputRaw = "2014-05-01 13:31:03.7";
String input = inputRaw.replace( " ", "T" ); // Adjust input to comply with the ISO 8601 standard.
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.UTC;
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, zone );  // The input lacks an offset. So specify the time zone by which to interpret the parsed input string. The resulting DateTime is then adjusted to the JVM’s current default time zone. So, *two* time zones were used in this line of code, one explicit, the other implicit.
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );  // Adjust to UTC.
DateTime dateTimeLosAngeles = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" ) );  // Adjust to US west coast time zone. DST is automatically applied as needed.
DateTime dateTimeKolkata = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );  // Adjust to India time, five and a half hours ahead of UTC.
```

All of these DateTime objects represent the same moment in the timeline of the history of the universe. Each has a different time-of-day (and possibly different date) to suit the "wall time" on clocks as likely seen by people in a particular locality.